# Can't decide which property to consider the Key - you can create one called 'ID' or mark one with SubSonicPrimaryKey attribute

Tags: subsonic3

I've researched the answers for this already and I can't work out whats wrong.

I'm getting this error on saving a record

Can't decide which property to consider the Key - you can create one called 'ID' or mark one with SubSonicPrimaryKey attribute

It relates to a table with an autoincrement primary key ID named 'ID' (int). I've tried adding [SubsonicPrimaryKey] to the public property (surely if its called ID I dont need to though). The table has EXACTLY the same schema design as another link table that is also set in my Save method, which doesnt cause an error.

This is my first Subsonic application and I've hit a complete wall with this error and have no idea what to try next.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: hi can anyone shed any light on this? I havent got any foreign key constraints set up in my database. Does that have any effect on this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Subsonic source code, you'll see that exact error message in Object.cs (ToSchemaTable method).

Subsonic is looking for the following :

a primary key set on the table in the database or SubSonicPrimaryKeyAttribute attribute
and then for

tableNameID where tableName is name of your table.
or

ID

Key

Subsonic is very flexible when it comes to that.

Can you provide your table schema ?